# Override / remove server-side validation in Symfony2.5

Tags: validation, symfony, server-side

Say I have the following form builder buildForm method:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{

$builder
    ->add(
        'travelTime',
        'datetime',
        array(
            'label' => 'Time',
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'time_widget' => 'single_text',
            'invalid_message' => 'Please enter a valid date and time',
        )
    )
    ->add(
        'acmeEntity',
        'entity',
        array(
            'label' => 'Acme Entity:',
            'class' => 'AcmeBundle:MyEntity',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
        )
    )
}
```

How can I override (or remove) validation for the 'acmeEntity' form field (and only that field) so that if I call:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
$form->isValid();
```

in a Controller, then acmeEntity will not be included in the validation that determines whether `$form->isValid()` returns true? I've tried adding `constraints => false`, to the field options, but I'm receiving this error message:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Validator/Constraints/FormValidator.php line 67
```

Does anyone know the proper way to disable server-side validation for a Symfony form field?

EDIT:

Note that I am not looking for how to disable validation completely. This can be done by adding:

```
    // Disable form validation
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function ($event) {
        $event->stopPropagation();
    }, 900); // Always set a higher priority than ValidationListener
```

to the bottom of a form builder.

Rather, I want to know how to completely disable validation for a *single* form field. Thanks everyone and good hunting!

Comment: How could acmeEntity be valid or invalid ?

Comment: Do you want to autosave that selection with the acme entity? I mean when form is submitted, automatically save the acme entity value to database with the other mapped fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a [custom form type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) for your entity and use the `'validation_groups' => false`. This should disable the validation only for this field.

The custom form type may look like that:

```
// .../Your/OwnBundle/Form/Type/AcmeEntityType.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class AcmeEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => false
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'entity';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_entity';
    }
}
```

You can then use:

```
$builder
    ->add(
        'travelTime',
        'datetime',
        array(
            'label' => 'Time',
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'time_widget' => 'single_text',
            'invalid_message' => 'Please enter a valid date and time',
        )
    )
    ->add(
        'acmeEntity',
        'acme_entity',
        array(
            'label' => 'Acme Entity:',
            'class' => 'AcmeBundle:MyEntity',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => false,
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: I went with a JavaScript approach to manually update a select option value in the name of a looming deadline, but this solution is correct. Thank you, sir.

Comment: Glad if I could help a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you call `buildForm()` from `MyEntityType` extending `AbstractType` so just use the options resolver by adding the function `setDefaultOptions()` in your type as said in the symphony doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#disabling-validation)

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => false,
    ));
}
```

Comment: This does not work -- you have to add:

```$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function ($event) {
            $event->stopPropagation();
        }, 900);
```

at the bottom of the form builder if you want to completely remove validation for all fields. Note that I am only looking for ways to completely disable it for a *single* field though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I have used it in the past :

1. Create a validation group for your MainEntity
2. Add this validation group to your form
3. Do not add this validation group to AcmeEntity